# Xcode Instruments does not show Symbols in new Apple M1 Pro machines

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1, instruments

I am trying to check performance issues for my project, when I profile and try to debug the performance issues all I can see masked address spaces and there is no information on code.

Has anyone faced this?
I cross-checked with all my team members and people with Intel are able to see file/ code information but all M1 Macbooks face the same issue.